# Can you explain the role of "que" in the following statement:

Tags: que

> Dès lors nous n’eûmes plus de repos ***que*** nous n’eussions
> retrouvé, dans les ouvrages contemporains, une trace quelconque de ces
> noms extraordinaires qui avaient si fort éveillé notre curiosité.

Alexandre Dumas: *Les trois mousquetaires* /Préface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que))
>
> **I.** − Empl. conjonctionnels
> **A.** − Conj. de sub.
> **6.** [Introd. une sub. circ.]
> **a)** [Circ. de temps]
> α) […]
> **β) [Empl. seul, introduisant une temporelle dans des systèmes exprimant la simultanéité ou la postériorité]**
> **− [Précédé d'une phrase nég.] Que ne + verbe au subj.** **Avant que, tant que**.
> • Roland, dans son cercle étroit de chevalerie, courait après Angélique; les conquérants de première race poursuivent une plus haute souveraine: point de repos pour eux qu'ils n'aient pressé dans leurs bras cette divinité couronnée de tours, épouse du Temps, fille du Ciel et mère des dieux (Chateaubr., Mém., t. 3, 1848, p. 425).
> • Je n'aurais point de repos que je n'aie contemplé une chose si merveilleuse (A. France, Thaïs, 1890, p. 270).

This is saying that from some point on they suppressed all leisure in their life with the intention of keeping it that way until they could find in contemporary books those extraordinary names that had made them curious. the point is made precise through "dès lors", as this adverb refers to a particular instant to be mentioned in the context (before). Notice the subjunctive in the sentence and in the examples (eussions retrouvé, aient pressé, aie contemplé).